# How do I deserialize JSON into a List<SomeType> with Kotlin + Jackson

Tags: json, jackson, kotlin

What is the correct syntax to deserialize the following JSON:

```
[ {
  "id" : "1",
  "name" : "Blues"
}, {
  "id" : "0",
  "name" : "Rock"
} ]
```

I tried:

```
//Works OK
val dtos  = mapper.readValue(json, List::class.java)
```

However I want:

```
val dtos : List<GenreDTO>  = mapper.readValue(json, 
    List<GenreDTO>::class.java)
```

The above syntax is not correct and gives: `only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

***NOTE:*** *The answer from @IRus is also correct, it was being modified at the same time I wrote this to fill in more details.*

You should use the [Jackson + Kotlin module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) or you will have other problems deserializing into Kotlin objects when you do no have a default constructor.

Your first sample of the code:

```
val dtos  = mapper.readValue(json, List::class.java)
```

Is returning an inferred type of `List<*>` since you did not specify more type information, and it is actually a `List<Map<String,Any>>` which is not really "working OK" but is not producing any errors.  It is unsafe, not typed.

The second code should be:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue

val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
// ...
val genres: List<GenreDTO> = mapper.readValue(json)
```

You do not need anything else on the right side of the assignment, the Kotlin module for Jackson will reify the generics and create the `TypeReference` for Jackson internally.  Notice the `readValue` import, you need that or `.*` for the `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin` package to have the extension functions that do all of the magic.

A slightly different alternative that also works:

```
val genres = mapper.readValue<List<GenreDTO>>(json)
```

There is no reason to NOT use the extension functions and the add-on module for Jackson.  It is small and solves other issues that would require you to jump through hoops to make a default constructor, or use a bunch of annotations.  With the module, your class can be normal Kotlin (optional to be `data` class):

```
class GenreDTO(val id: Int, val name: String)
```

Comment: I was using the Kotlin module for Jackson, and had tried something like this, but forgot the imports.

Comment: I am hoping that https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9238 will allow a library to kinda tell the IDE what imports are important for it.

Comment: I just realised that this does not work with generics. mapper.readValue<List<T>>(json) will result in a list of hashmaps. I get why, but I seem to be unable to find a workaround...

Comment: @UncleBob it is a limitation of reified generics.  Is `<T>` from a local class, or function, and how is that declared?  you have a special case here, and is maybe worthwhile to post a new question specific to using a generic parameter of a nested scope within your call to the function.

Answer (score 24):

The error you're getting is about following expression:

```
List<GenreDTO>::class.java
```

Because of how jvm treats generics there's no separate class for `List<GenreDTO>` thus compiler complains. Similarly in Java the following will not compile:

```
List<GenreDTO>.getClass()
```

Here's a sample that will deserialize the list properly:

```
val value:List<GenreDTO> = mapper.readValue(json, object : TypeReference<List<GenreDTO>>() {})
```

As @JaysonMinard has pointed out you can use [jackson-module-kotlin](http://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) to simplify the invocation to:

```
val genres: List<GenreDTO> = mapper.readValue(json)
// or
val genres = mapper.readValue<List<GenreDTO>>(json)
```

This is possible because of [`reified type parameters`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters). Consider looking at [`Extensions`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/kotlin/Extensions.kt) to find out details.

Comment: Since he should be using the Jackson Kotlin module, this should be simplified as described in the documentation for that module (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) .  There is a simple sample there for doing just this.

Comment: worked like a charm, nothing else did:

val value:List<GenreDTO> = mapper.readValue(json, object : TypeReference<List<GenreDTO>>() {})

Answer (score 7):

Following code works well for me:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.registerKotlinModule



val json = """[ {
  "id" : "1",
  "name" : "Blues"
}, {
  "id" : "0",
  "name" : "Rock"
} ]"""

data class GenreDTO(val id: Int, val name: String)

val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val obj: List<GenreDTO> = mapper.readValue(json)
    obj.forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

This work because of extension function defined inside jackson-kotlin-module (that used [reified](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) generics):

```
 public inline fun <reified T: Any> ObjectMapper.readValue(content: String): T = readValue(content, object: TypeReference<T>() {})
```

Thanks @JaysonMinard for notify me about it.

Output:

```
GenreDTO(id=1, name=Blues)
GenreDTO(id=0, name=Rock)
```

Comment: This code isn't correct.  It only works because your data type is an Array.  Using `::class.java` is wrong ALWAYS when generics are involved.

Comment: Thank you, @JaysonMinard i found extension function that i doesn't noticed before.

Comment: if my json contains the field object, how should i customise ?

Comment: What do you mean by "field object", and what you like to customize?

Comment: @IRus this is the magic code 'registerKotlinModule()'

Comment: @ItaiSpector No, this is simple extension function

Comment: @IRus That simple extension made it work, cheers