# Spring Boot REST Service: JSON Deserialization Not Working

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jackson, kotlin

I'm working on a REST service using spring-boot and Kotlin.  (I should mention it's my first time using both.)  I'm having trouble getting Jackson to deserialize JSON from a POST request using this code:

```
@RequestMapping("cloudservice/login/{uuid}", method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST))
fun login(@PathVariable(value="uuid")uuid: String, @RequestBody user: CloudServiceUser ) : ResponseEntity<CloudServiceUser> {

    val cloudServiceFactory : Class<CloudServiceFactory> = cloudServiceRepository.cloudServiceExtensions[UUID.fromString(uuid)] ?: throw InvalidPathVariableException("Invalid UUID.")
    var token : String
    try {
        token = cloudServiceFactory.newInstance().authenticationService.login(user.userId, user.password)
    } catch (e:Exception ){
        throw CloudServiceException(e.message)
    }

    return ResponseEntity(CloudServiceUser(userId=user.userId, password = "", token = token),HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

The user object is simply:

```
data class CloudServiceUser(val userId: String, val password:String, val token:String)
```

I get the error

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of com.irotsoma.cloudbackenc.cloudservice.CloudServiceUser: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@682b15d6; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.irotsoma.cloudbackenc.cloudservice.CloudServiceUser: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@682b15d6; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:229) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:213) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:197) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:147) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:125) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:261) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.irotsoma.cloudbackenc.cloudservice.CloudServiceUser: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@682b15d6; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:261) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:1420) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1011) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1201) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:314) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:148) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2913) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:226) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

However, the serializing in the return statement works just fine to serialize to a JSON object and sends the response.  It's just the deserialization that isn't working.

If I change the body variable to a String and manually create mapper, it also works fine. Like this:

```
@RequestMapping("cloudservice/login/{uuid}", method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST))
fun login(@PathVariable(value="uuid")uuid: String, @RequestBody user: String ) : ResponseEntity<CloudServiceUser> {

    val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule())
    val mapperData: CloudServiceUser = mapper.readValue(user)


    val cloudServiceFactory : Class<CloudServiceFactory> = cloudServiceRepository.cloudServiceExtensions[UUID.fromString(uuid)] ?: throw InvalidPathVariableException("Invalid UUID.")
    var token : String
    try {
        token = cloudServiceFactory.newInstance().authenticationService.login(mapperData.userId, mapperData.password)
    } catch (e:Exception ){
        throw CloudServiceException(e.message)
    }

    return ResponseEntity(CloudServiceUser(userId=mapperData.userId, password = "", token = token),HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

Any ideas?

It's an open source project, so feel free to browse it if you need more info:  https://github.com/irotsoma/cloudbackenc.  Note that it is in a very early state at the moment.

EDIT:  Just wanted to add a note about my troubles with Integration tests as noted in comments on the accepted answer.  I ended up never getting the integration test to be able to deserialize the response (though the REST controller side of things worked fine just like in production).  So I found a workaround using a Map object, which for some reason it was able to deserialize to, and then manually processing it rather than using the class object.  Since it's just a problem with the test and not the code being tested, this was fine for me.

```
val returnValue = template.postForEntity("REQUEST URL", httpEntity, Map::class.java)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to help Jackson in deserializing data classes as indicated in the error message. You can do so by registering [jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) in `ObjectMapper` like so:

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule())
```

To tell spring about your own customized `ObjectMapper` [define a `@Bean` and mark it as `@Primary`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper):

```
@Configuration
open class ObjectMapperConfiguration {
  @Bean
  @Primary
  open fun objectMapper() = ObjectMapper().apply { 
    registerModule(KotlinModule()) 
  }
}
```

Further reading:

- [How to use jackson to deserialize to Kotlin collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368328/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialize-to-kotlin-collections)
- [How do I deserialize JSON into a List<SomeType> with Kotlin + Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716697/how-do-i-deserialize-json-into-a-listsometype-with-kotlin-jackson/34717277#34717277)

Comment: Works great!  Any advice on getting this to work with an integration test?  I'm getting the same error.  I created an HttpEntity with a header using the JSON MediaType and used a TestRestTemplate.postForEntity.  Seems to deserialize for the request, but the REST service is throwing the same error even though it works fine with a REST client when it's running normally.

Comment: @irotsoma make sure you custom `ObjectMapperConfiguration` is `@Imported` in test.

Comment: The first thing I tried was adding `@Import(ObjectMapperConfiguration::class)` to the test class along with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(CentralController::class)
@WebIntegrationTest`.  Any ideas on what else to check?

Comment: @irotsoma did you figure out a solution for the tests?

Comment: The error might also originate from missing `@RequestBody` on the controller parameter.