# How do I create a list in JSON equivalent to a list on Kotlin?

Tags: json, kotlin, ktor

I'm learning Ktor and trying to test a POST request implementation I made using the example model given [here](https://ktor.io/docs/creating-http-apis.html#order_model). However, I have no idea how to make a proper list in JSON that Ktor could read and deserialize as a list.

I've tried:

```
{
  "number": "2022-04-28",
  "contents": {
    "OrderItem": {
      "item": "Tea",
      "amount": 5,
      "price": 2.99
    },
    "OrderItem": {
      "item": "Coffee",
      "amount": 2,
      "price": 4.99
    }
  }
}
```

But I get an internal server error whenever I try to send the POST request.

Comment: contents should be array.

Comment: You probably got the error because what you have posted is invalid json. Objects (`{ }`) in js/json are dicts, and must have unique keys (you used `"OrderItem"` twice). Arrays (`[ ]`) in js/json are lists.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html#example-json-serialization Is this helpful?

Comment: @SeanSutherland The link doesn't really help. I'm trying to make a list of OrderItem objects, with contents as the list. I'm confused, do I just give each OrderItem object a random name? 
Not sure if it matters, the JSON is being made in a .http file for manual testing.

Comment: Those aren't names, they're dictionary keys. You want a list, not a dict. @sidgate's answer is the correct way to have a list of objects in Json. Json doesn't have a concept of object types, you have to do that part in Kotlin. As for interpreting it in kotlin, google "deserialize json in kotlin" and find a tutorial or example code. You can come back and ask another question if you get stuck and show us what you've tried, since that's a different question than the one you asked.

Comment: This might help you start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716697/how-do-i-deserialize-json-into-a-listsometype-with-kotlin-jackson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contents` should be a list `[]` of objects

```
{
  "number": "2022-04-28",
  "contents": [
    {
      "item": "Tea",
      "amount": 5,
      "price": 2.99
    },
    {
      "item": "Coffee",
      "amount": 2,
      "price": 4.99
    }
  ]
}
```